# Visual studio code - _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-sticky"

Tags: tkinter, visual, studio, sticky

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un archivo ventana.pyw desde Visual Studio Code. Al ejecutarlo directamente desde el explorador de Windows con Python funciona pero cuando lo intento desde Visual Studio Code me sale el error en la consola de la aplicación y no se abre.

El error de la aplicación me empieza aparecer al tener `sticky="e"` o `anchor="e"`.

Error que me sale:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ventana.pyw", line 13, in <module>
    cuadroTexto=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre:", sticky="e") # Texto
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3177, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-sticky"
```

Código del archivo:

```
# Para Importar todas las clases de Tkinter
from tkinter import *

# Crear la variable ventana
root = Tk()
root.title("Nombre") # Titulo de la ventana
root.config(bg="black")

# Crear espacio de trabajo
miFrame=Frame(root, width=500, height=400)
miFrame.pack() # Poner en la ventana

# Nombre
Label1=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre:") # Texto
Label1.grid(row="0", column="0", sticky="e") # Posicion

Entry1=Entry(miFrame) # Entrada de texto
Entry1.grid(row="0", column="1") # Posicion

# Apellidos
Label2=Label(miFrame, text="Apellidos:") # Texto
Label2.grid(row="1", column="0", sticky="e") # Posicion

Entry2=Entry(miFrame) # Entrada de texto
Entry2.grid(row="1", column="1") # Posicion

# 
Label3=Label(miFrame, text="De donde eres:") # Texto
Label3.grid(row="2", column="0", sticky="e") # Posicion

Entry3=Entry(miFrame) # Entrada de texto
Entry3.grid(row="2", column="1") # Posicion

# Abrir ventana
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale ya me he dado cuenta mientras escribía esto, por alguna razón la terminal se quedó pillada y he tenido que reiniciar el programa.

Concretamente en este trozo.

```
cuadroTexto=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre:", sticky="e") # Texto
```

Antes sin darme cuenta dejé puesto:

```
# Nombre
cuadroTexto=Label(miFrame, text="Nombre:") # Texto
cuadroTexto.grid(row="0", column="0", sticky="e") # Posicion

cuadroTexto=Entry(miFrame) # Entrada de texto
cuadroTexto.grid(row="0", column="1") # Posicion

# Apellidos
cuadroTexto=Label(miFrame, text="Apellidos:") # Texto
cuadroTexto.grid(row="1", column="0", sticky="e") # Posicion

cuadroTexto=Entry(miFrame) # Entrada de texto
cuadroTexto.grid(row="1", column="1") # Posicion
```

Al declararlos con el mismo nombre dejo la aplicación pillada ahí y al no cerrar la ejecución anterior no me dejaba lanzar la nueva.

Answer (score 0):

yo me equivoque en el label, en ves de poner

```
text = "asdad"
```

puse

```
texto = "afsdfd"
```

Comment: Cual sería la relación entre tu publicación y la pregunta?